Angular microfront end w/ tailwindcss
i use module federation and multirepo in angular, i have a shell, an app (MFE) and a shared-ui
so in my shared-ui i have installed tailwindcss, i have my file tailwind.config.js and a styles.scss where i have the three imports of tailwind,
i installed this library in my MFE and in my shell and i import the shared-ui styles in my style everything work fine, and i did the same in my shell,
However, when loaded within the shell application, only the shell's Tailwind classes are applied.
how to resolve this
Thank you
